# Is there a way to show the errorTip (error ToolTip) to the left of the target?

Tags: apache-flex, tooltip

I'm creating an errorTip that gets displayed when the user mouses over an image. I would like the popup to appear to the **left** of the image, but the only properties I can pass to create the toolTip are "errorTipRight", "errorTipAbove" and "errorTipBelow".

Any thoughts?

**Sample code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.ToolTip;
            import mx.managers.ToolTipManager;
            [Embed(source="assets/some_image.png")]
            [Bindable]
            private var myIcon:Class;

            private var myToolTip:ToolTip;

            private function showToolTip(evt:MouseEvent, text:String):void
            {
                var pt:Point = new Point(evt.currentTarget.x, evt.currentTarget.y);
                pt = evt.currentTarget.parent.contentToGlobal(pt);

                // I WANT TO POP THE ERRORTIP UP TO THE LEFT HERE INSTEAD OF ABOVE.
                myToolTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(text, pt.x, pt.y, "errorTipAbove") as ToolTip; 
                var yOffset:int =  myToolTip.height + 5;
                myToolTip.y -= yOffset;
            }

            // Remove the tooltip
            private function killToolTip():void
            {
                ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(myToolTip);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Image source="{myIcon}" mouseOver="showToolTip(event, 'My ToolTip Message Goes Here')" mouseOut="killToolTip()" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a replacement for the ToolTipBorder class and assign that as the skin for your ToolTip.  I would do this by copying the ToolTipBorder source and modifying the updateDisplayList and borderMetrics methods to include a new "errorTipLeft" style to the switch statements in those methods.  Then assign that skin class to the ToolTip class in CSS.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks Wade!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you subtract the width of the tooltip from the pt.x when you give the coordinates to the ToolTipManager?

```
myToolTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(text, (pt.x - somewidth), pt.y, "errorTipAbove") as ToolTip;
```

Comment: The positioning of the toolTip isn't the issue. The issue is where the arrow portion of the toolTip is drawn. If you select "errorTipAbove" it draws the arrow at the bottom of the toolTip so that it points down at the source control that triggered the toolTip. I would like the arrow to be drawn on the right side of the toolTip to point to my image.